# Add additional content to WooCommerce layout?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to add additional content (such as a banner image, an additional loop) to the WooCommerce plugin, but I'm having trouble trying to output such said content.

I'm trying to make WooCommerce output `<div>`s with `<img>` tags in the `wrapper-end.php` template area after the `<div>`s, but nothing comes up.

I've also tried placing the extra content after `<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>` in `woocommerce.php`, but it duplicates itself for every single page afterwards.

I'm confused. Is it possible? Am I doing something wrong?

[image: Woocommerce Layout]

I'm trying to do something like this.

Can someone share their experience?

Answer (score 3):

if you don't use the catch-all `woocommerce_content()` function, but the hooks instead, you can customize every page individually by just copying all the files from `woocommerce/template` to `yourtheme/woocommerce`. See [woocommerce docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/#usinghooks) for more info.

The templates will also show you the other hooks & filters that you can use to place your content.

Comment: what do you mean by 'hooks instead'? does that mean if I output all the hook functions manually, I can add additional content to the site? how would I know all the function hooks that are executed in woocommerce_content()?

Comment: You can test by just copy pasting their example code. With that code, basically you're saying which HTML to put before and after the main content. So you start out by removing the woocommerce.php method, and WooCommerce will fall back to its templates in `woocommerce/templates`. First you make sure that the shop content (product pages & listings, checkout etc.) is properly wrapped so that it fits in your theme (if it doesn't already!), then you can alter each of those templates like I described. If that's too difficult, I guess this is not the way to go (hire a developer).

Comment: I'm finally free now, and I'm testing what you just said out -- turns out I misunderstood how the remove and add action functions worked, once I added in the codes above the Loop and below the Loop into their respective function areas, took out woocommerce.php, everything worked just as fine, and I can now include additional stuff whereever I want. Thanks!

Comment: how do I actually filter that out?

Comment: Everything you put in the hooks (`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content'` etc.) will indeed be displayed on every page. You can put conditionals around this, like is_shop() etc. to check what kind of page it is and wrap accordingly, or alternatively you could edit the templates like I suggested to do it on a page level.

Comment: yeah, I'm trying out conditionals but I'm looking at a 'best practice' way to go... I think I might have to do some trial and error on some templates to see where they actually get displayed. Ugh, why couldn't there be at least some documentation on which page displays what, etc? :(